# Should you NEVER create a new object of any other class in another class' method?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have been trying to understand Dependency injection and Ioc and all related concepts to it, but have not made much progress.

What I have understood is to make my class (say A) testable (my class which uses object of class B), I should have the object injected into my class' constructor like this:

```
class A{

    B class_B_Object;

    A(B class_B_Object){
        this.class_B_Object = class_B_Object;
    }
}
```

So, my question here is, is it safe to say that I should never have something like `var classBObject = new B()` in any of my class A's methods?

Comment: "never" is a strong word, I wouldn't use it here. The main idea is that you should inject a value whenever you can.

Comment: A sentence containing "never" is never safe to say.

Comment: @alfasin how so? If instances are created via a factory, the same questions apply. There could even be cached instances returned by the factory. The point is about how the object is acquired for use, not created

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say...

Comment: I am saying it is not about how dependencies are created. It is about how they are acquired. So having calling a static factory would be just as much of an obstacle to testing as calling a constructor. However, perhaps that point is simply too obvious to remark on.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am in my nascent years of development, and kind of worried that I don't understand such concepts completely.
Is this something that comes with experience? What are some sources I can use to get better at these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never is a very strong word, and you should use it very carefully. Depending on what `A` and `B` are, it may be perfectly normal for `A` to create (and usually return) an instance of `B`. The main point of testability here is that if `A` **uses** an instance of `B` and relies on its logic, you should probably have an easy way to inject a mock instance of `B` where this logic is controlled (i.e. - mocked away), so when you write a unit test for `A` you're just testing its logic, not the underlying logic of `B`.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to making your code easily unit testable in isolation is by using a weak coupling between your layers. This means that your `A` class constructor should not take `B` class but rather `IB` interface that some potential `B` class might implement. This would allow you to substitute this interface in your unit test with something you have control over - a mock because you are testing the `A` class, not `B`.

As far as your question about `var classBObject = new B()` is concerned, it would really depend on the situation but in general, it is better to have this instance provided from the outside.

Comment: That was true... many years ago. Java mocking frameworks are perfectly capable of mocking concrete classes nowadays. I'm not saying weak coupling is a bad thing, but that using interfaces in a systematic way often introduces noise and makes the code more complex than it needs to be for no real advantage.

Comment: I agree with you that it should not be systematic. However it is not only about unit testing. By using interfaces and abstract classes the different layers of your application will be more easily re-used in different contexts and environments.

Comment: Programming to interfaces, generally abstractions instead of concretions, is a very good practice but I think it is orthogonal to this question.